# DNS Interpreter through EchoClient

Tags: java, bufferedreader, streamreader, serversocket

I have been trying to play around with Java's Socket class and I have hit a tough spot. I have three classes: EchoServerTemplate, ConcurrentServer, and EchoClient.

I want to send a website(www.google.com) from a client to the server and then have the server return the IP address. I think I am extremely close, but I do not know how BufferedStreamer in Java works well enough to figure out the error messages.

Here is my code for all three classes:

EchoServerTemplate (This is where I want the Web Address to be translated):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class  EchoServerTemplate extends Thread 
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 6007;
        public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
        Socket clientSocket;
                 EchoServerTemplate(Socket cs){
            clientSocket = cs;
        }

    public void run(){
        InputStream fromClient = null;
        OutputStream toClient = null;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                String printaddress = null;

        try {
                    while(true){
                    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    fromClient = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    try {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(fromClient.toString());
                printaddress = address.toString();

                    }
                    catch(UnknownHostException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    toClient = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                while (printaddress != null) {
                                    toClient.write(printaddress.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    toClient.flush();
                                        printaddress = null;
                }


                fromClient.close();
                toClient.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                    }
                }
        catch (IOException ioe) { 
                    ioe.printStackTrace();}
        }
}
```

ConcurrentServer:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ConcurrentServer {

    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
               try {
            int serverPortNumber = 6007;
                        ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(serverPortNumber);

            while (true) {

                         Socket clientSocket  = sock.accept();
                         EchoServerTemplate thread = new EchoServerTemplate(clientSocket);
                         thread.start();    
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) { 
                ioe.printStackTrace();}

    }

}
```

EchoClient:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6007);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: ");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to the host.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("IP Address: " + in.readLine());
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

The task I accomplished before this was just having the ConcurrentServer repeat what was typed on the client. In modifying the code I may have accidentally messed something up. Here are the error messages I am receiving:

> run: www.google.com Exception in thread "main"
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)  at
>   EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:31) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   (total time: 4 seconds)

Any help is appreciated. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: You want to send a *hostname* from the client to the server. It is a pointless exercise. The InetAddress class already does all this, with no server required.

Comment: I guess that part is irrelevant... I cannot get a string to go from the server to the client. Obviously I could do it all from the client easily, but I would like for the server to return a string.

Comment: What line is EchoClient.java:31?

Comment: Not sure, I am away from my main develop machine right now. Those three classes are the only ones I am using so if you just copy them and put Concurrent and the Template on in the same project, you will see exactly what I do. However that is a lot of work on your part haha.